# images in a ul breaks up when resizing the browser

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, html-lists

Take a look at my link (http://brothersindesign.com/) and resize the browser as you can see the images break up and you can see the background.

any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <title>mock</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>




    </script>


</head>

    <body>

            <div class="head">

                <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li>-</li>
                <li><a href="#">Journal</a></li>
                <li>-</li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li>-</li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div><!--

         --><div class="work">
                <ul>

                    <li><span>
                    <div class="view">  
                    <img src="img/one.jpg" />  
                    <div class="mask">  
                    <h2>Title</h2>  
                    <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>  
                    </div>  
                    </div> 
                    </span></li><!--

                    --><li><span>
                    <div class="view">  
                    <img src="img/two.jpg" />  
                    <div class="mask">  
                    <h2>Title</h2>  
                    <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>  
                    </div>  
                    </div></span></li>

                </ul>

                <ul>

                    <li><span>
                    <div class="view">  
                    <img src="img/one.jpg" />  
                    <div class="mask">  
                    <h2>Title</h2>  
                    <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>  
                    </div>  
                    </div> 
                    </span></li><!--

                    --><li><span>
                    <div class="view">  
                    <img src="img/two.jpg" />  
                    <div class="mask">  
                    <h2>Title</h2>  
                    <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>  
                    </div>  
                    </div></span></li>

                </ul>

                <ul>

                    <li><span>
                    <div class="view">  
                    <img src="img/one.jpg" />  
                    <div class="mask">  
                    <h2>Title</h2>  
                    <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>  
                    </div>  
                    </div> 
                    </span></li><!--

                    --><li><span>
                    <div class="view">  
                    <img src="img/two.jpg" />  
                    <div class="mask">  
                    <h2>Title</h2>  
                    <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>  
                    </div>  
                    </div></span></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

  </body>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.head{
width:100%;
height:2em;
background-color:#2b2b2b;
position:relative;

}

.nav{
float:right;
margin-right:10em;
margin-top:0.40em;

}

.head .nav li{

display:inline-block;
color:#ffffff;

}

.head .nav li a{

color:#ffffff;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
font-size:0.90em;


}

.head .nav li a:hover{
border-bottom:1px #ffffff solid;


}



.work{
position:absolute;

}

ul {
margin:0; /*CSS reset*/
padding:0;/*CSS reset*/
}


li{
display:table-cell;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}


.view {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;
}
.view .mask, .view .content {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
top: 0;
left: 0
}

.view h2 {
text-transform: uppercase;
color: black;
font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
font-size: 17px;
margin: 20px 0 0 0
}

.view a.info {
font-family: 'JuliusSansOne', sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#2b2b2b;
position:relative;
top:2em;


}
.view a.info:hover {
color:blue;
}

.view img { 
transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view .mask {
opacity: 0;
background-color: yellow; 
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.view h2 {
transform: translateY(-100px);
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.view info{
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.view:hover img { 
transform: scale(1.1);
} 
.view:hover .mask { 
opacity: 1;
}
.view:hover h2,
.view:hover p,
.view:hover a.info {
opacity: 1;
transform: translateY(0px);
}

.view:hover a.info {
transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: What a mess! Looks like a bunch of tables and position absolutes. You really shouldn't use those unless you have a specific reason to. This layout could be easily made with min/max and media queries.

Comment: There is no table i used an unordered list and it looks messy because there is a lot that is in each li.. If you click on the link you will see what I'm trying to achieve, you will also se the problem I'm having.

Comment: It appears you and I have the same issue.  It's only in Chrome though.  And so far, the only similarity between the two that I can find is we both use `translate()` in our CSS.  Try taking that out and see what happens.